# How to use DIR-842 as an access point?

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a D-Link DIR-842 that I'd like to use as an access point as I already have a wireless router my ISP sent me.

Browsing the Web GUI I can find any setting that'd make it an access point.

How do turn a DIR-842 to a wireless access point?

Comment: Not a 100% but you may want to look at this - - http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=iht3s6shjjt7a34jvv40m64r30&topic=40856.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, but you'll not get 4 LAN ports from it, only 3.

[The thing is that the WAN port cant be used for anything else than WAN.](https://superuser.com/a/1060289/251330)

[To setup DIR-842 as an access point](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=iht3s6shjjt7a34jvv40m64r30&topic=40856.0)

1. Login to the routers web GUI (dlinkrouter.local)
2. Give it a static LAN IP not available in your ISP routers DHCP pool so that you can access it later
3. Disable the DHCP server in the DIR-842.
4. Connect a cable from your ISP router to one of the LAN ports of the 842.
5. Login to the router and disable pretty much everything not needed and setup wireless.

You've now turned it into an access point. You can use the other 3 Gbps ports for connecting other stuff.

[image: LAN IP and DHCP off]