# Using DIR-842 with Hurricane Electric's IPv6 Tunnelbroker

Tags: router, ipv6

I've a [D-Link DIR-842](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=dir842) (that's got the new Web UI) and I'm using it as [an access point](https://superuser.com/questions/1244649/using-dir-842-as-an-access-point), connected to my cable modem.

> Cable Modem [LAN] --eth--> [LAN] DIR-842

My ISP doesn't provide any IPv6 access so I have to use a tunnel. I've always been using [Hurricane Electric's Tunnelbroker](https://www.tunnelbroker.net/) and now I'd like to use my new DIR-842 to connect to the tunnel as it supports **IPv6 in IPv4 tunnel**.

I've added the DIR-842 to the cable modems DMZ and HE is able to ping my cable modem. The DIR-842 is also assigning IPv6 addresses from my HE prefix. So far everything is working.

But, I noticed that I can't enter a **Local IPv4 Address**, which seems to be breaking the tunnel as my laptop can't connect to the IPv6 net.

[image: Local IPv4 Address: Not Available]

In the manual for DIR-859 it seems like you should be able to manually enter a **Local IPv4 Address** but this doesn't seem possible for DIR-842.

Is it possible to set the **Local IPv4 Address** on the DIR-842?

*(The 2001:470:a:a and 2001:470:a:b subnets are fictional)*

## Updates

- The cable modem got the public IPv4 address and the DIR-842 is using a static local address *(and is connected through a LAN port to the cable modem)*. That static local one is DMZ.

Comment: That shouldn't be a large problem; if you have only one WAN IPv4 address, I'd expect the router to use it automatically. However, _which device_ is the one with the WAN address – is it the DIR, or is it the cable modem?

Comment: The cable modem got the public IPv4 as it's being used as an access point too.

Comment: That's probably why the DIR isn't letting you choose the address; it knows that it's behind a NAT and doesn't bother. (If it did, you'd have needed to select the internal address anyway, not the WAN one.) This still has a chance of working, but my wild guess is that the cable modem itself doesn't properly NAT the tunnel (which is neither TCP nor UDP, but protocol-41). Can't give a good answer though.

Comment: It lets protocol 41 through so all I need is to specify the static local one as local IPv4. The modem will do NAT for the DMZ.

Comment: Am unable to set the static 192.168.0.0/24 address as WAN IP, because "The network id is the same with LAN".