# Network devices behind switch are not seen on the wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, switch

Setup:
I have a new mesh network but am using my old router as a switch to use an Ethernet connection for certain devices including my TV (LG C1), my HTPC (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) and my Nintendo Switch, set up as follows:

Internet -> Modem -> ASUS ZenWiFi AX Mini AX1800 base unit -> D-Link DIR-842 (old router) -> other devices

Certain features that used to work when everything was connected to a single router are no longer functioning, specifically, those that require my phone to see the device by being on the same network.

Example 1.
My LG ThinkQ Android app is unable to connect to the TV while the TV is connected by Ethernet but is able to connect while the TV is on wifi.

Example 2.
The KDE Connect app no longer is able to connect my phone with my HTPC.  The PC does not have wifi, so I am unable to connect that way, but, again, back when the PC was connected to the primary (i.e. only) router, this feature worked a treat.

The issue seems to be that devices behind the switch are not visible on the same network as those on the wifi network.  This seems to be confirmed by the fact that the ASUS Router app I use to manage the network shows the D-Link but not any device behind it (as far as I can tell.  There are a lot of devices on the network that I haven't identified yet.).

The Asus base has one Ethernet line in and only one Ethernet line out, so I can only send an Ethernet cable out to one device, hence the need for a switch.

How can I configure my network to have devices behind the switch visible to devices on the rest of the network?

---

Edit: Looking at the D-Link's manual [here](https://support.dlink.com/resource/PRODUCTS/DIR-842/REVC/DIR-842_REVC_MANUAL_v3.00_WW_EN.pdf), I can't find anything about switch mode, bridge mode, or AP mode.  I disabled DHCP, but that seems to have broken the web GUI, so I've reset the router and am back where I started.

Having learned a bit from the answers so far, I am currently attempting a solution based on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1244649/how-to-use-dir-842-as-an-access-point).  I will update if that succeeds or fails.

---

Edit 2: Success.

The other superuser post on how to use DIR-842 as an access point provided the solution.  I believe my mistake was interpreting WAN as the data-in port and LAN as the data-out port.  In the end, I did connect the Asus to a D-Link LAN port, not WAN. I apologize for the confusion and am grateful for the help.

Comment: Well, sounds like you haven't configure it to operate in switch mode? (Often known as bridge mode or AP mode.)

Comment: @TomYan By "it", do you mean the Asus or the D-Link?  Or both?

Comment: Just the D-Link. There's a chance that you *could* make the ASUS one do that as well, if `modem` is actually a `modem+router`, but if none if your devices (other than the ASUS router) is connected to the `modem` directly, then in terms of your goal here, you don't need to.

Comment: You need to disable the DHCP service on the D-Link router. Or if it's available, configure that Wifi router as a WAP, which might allow the WAN port to be used as another LAN port.

Comment: @sawdust Disabling DHCP won't make the WAN and LAN *one* broadcast domain. In terms of that approach, the OP would need to avoid using the WAN port.

Comment: ok, when using the Dlink as a switch, are all the connections into it on LAN ports, or do you have anything connected to the WAN port? if you look at the IP addresses on the different sets of systems are they in the same subnet? you should feel free to post IP addresses within your LAN, as long as they are not your public IP. also check your wifi device to make sure that a feature called "client isolation" or "ap isolation" did not get accidentally enabled. its designed to prevent people at a coffee shop from hacking each other, so it will block devices on the LAN from talking.

Comment: @TomYan -- Apparently you don't understand what I wrote, so your comment to me is worthless.

Comment: @FrankThomas I intend to have an Ethernet cable coming from the lone LAN port of the Asus into the WAN port of the D-Link.

Comment: ok, if you want to use the WAN port, you will need to put the router in bridge mode (hopefully it supports it). consider using a lan port on the dlink for that connection, or put it in bridge mode. consult the dlink devices manual for instructions. by using the WAN port, you effectively have two networks, and consumer grade internet access routers use NAT between the WAN port and LAN ports, which is clearly not what you want. oh and do disable DHCP on the dlink if it is enabled. in your goal-architecture, you want one DHCP server for the whole LAN.

Comment: Disconnect the DLink from everything. Power it up. Connect a PC to a DLink LAN port. Disable DHCP, and save new config. shut down DLink & PC. Connect a DLink LAN port to main router. Power up DLink & PC. PC should have Internet access.

Comment: @sawdust See, you have to mention `Connect a DLink LAN port to main router`, otherwise *your* comment would be worthless *to the OP*. Mine was *not* supposed to be worthwhile *to you* anyway, but to prevent your comment from misleading the OP.

Comment: @TomYan -- Apparently you don't understand conditionals such as "*Or if it's available ...*" and "*might allow*". FYI there are wireless routers, that with just one configuration selection, repurposes the unit into WAP mode (and converts the WAN port into a 5th LAN port).

Comment: @sawdust *You* were the one who was having semantic issue. The problem was NOT you HADN'T mentioned that WAP/AP/bridge/switch mode, but rather, if *it's not available* (which would be the scenario you *must be* referring to with "disable DHCP" clause/instruction, "disabling DHCP" alone is not sufficient, because in that case, the OP has to avoid using the WAN port *at the same time*, because the WAN interface would be in another broadcast domain than the LAN is.